# gulp-connect and connect.reload

Tags: javascript, gulp, livereload

I am trying to set up a simple server to test out some d3.js stuff. I'm following a screencast on tagtree.tv. My code matches his, but I cannot get my index.html to reload when I make a change to my JS or SASS files.

I'm new to gulp so as far as I can tell things look OK, but that's based upon my assumption that a call to connect.reload() will reload whatever browser is looking at its content. It should be noted that the livereload JS is being inserted into my index.html file.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
d3play
 -bower_components
 -dist
   -css
   -scripts
 - node_modules
 -sass
 -scripts
 gulpfile.js
 index.html
 package.json
```

My gulpfile.js looks like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  connect = require('gulp-connect'),
  traceur = require('gulp-traceur'),
  sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');

gulp.task('connect', function(){
  connect.server({
    livereload: true
  });
});

gulp.task('reload', function(){
  gulp.src('./dist/**/*.*')
  .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('sass', function(){
  gulp.src('./sass/*.scss')
  .pipe(sass())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css'));
});

gulp.task('traceur', function(){
  gulp.src('./scripts/*.js')
  .pipe(traceur())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/scripts'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
  gulp.watch(['./sass/*.scss'], ['sass']);
  gulp.watch(['./scripts/*.js'], ['traceur']);
  gulp.watch(['./dist/**/*.*'], ['reload']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['connect', 'sass', 'traceur', 'watch']);
```

Comment: In addition, when I run `gulp` and save SASS or JS files the console output looks like the reload is working, it just does nothing in my browser.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [simple and **tested** livereload solution](https://github.com/dmitriz/gulp-automation) based on `connect` server and `connect-livereload` and `gulp-livereload` plugins that might help:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var connect = require('connect');
var connectLivereload = require('connect-livereload');
var opn = require('opn');
var gulpLivereload = require('gulp-livereload');

var config = {
    rootDir: __dirname,
    servingPort: 8080,

    // the files you want to watch for changes for live reload
    filesToWatch: ['*.{html,css,js}', '!Gulpfile.js']
}

// The default task - called when you run `gulp` from CLI
gulp.task('default', ['watch', 'serve']);

gulp.task('watch', ['connect'], function () {
  gulpLivereload.listen();
  gulp.watch(config.filesToWatch, function(file) {
    gulp.src(file.path)
      .pipe(gulpLivereload());
  });
});

gulp.task('serve', ['connect'], function () {
  return opn('http://localhost:' + config.servingPort);
});

gulp.task('connect', function(){
  return connect()
    .use(connectLivereload())
    .use(connect.static(config.rootDir))
    .listen(config.servingPort);
});
```

Comment: The detail with the `gulp.src` call inside `gulp.watch` for calling livereload was a lifesaver -- that handily fixed my own problems with `connect.reload()`. Thanks for this.

Comment: @rlafuente Glad to help. More recently I've been using https://github.com/mattdesl/budo for even simpler live reload setup.

Answer (score 0):

Faced with a similar situation where I was trying to do

```
gulp.watch(['path/to/**/*.foo'], ['doTheReload'])
```

I got it working by changing the reload to stream directly on the watch e.g.:

```
gulp.watch(['path/to/**/*.foo']).pipe(connect.reload());
```

Without knowing anything more than this, I'm guessing that the stream that `connect.reload()` expects is somehow different than the one provided by `gulp.src()`.

Comment: gulp.watch.pipe causes "is not a function" error in my case