# Gulp watch for css doesn't work

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

My gulp watch doesn't work for css. I have the following config:

```
var config = {
    port : 9007,
    devBaseUrl : "http://localhost",
    paths : {
        html : "./src/*.html",
        js : "./src/**/*.js",
        images : './src/images/*',
        css : [
          'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
          'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css',
          'node_modules/toastr/package/toastr.css',
            "src/css/main.css"

        ],
        dist : './dist',
        mainJS : './src/main.js'
    }
};
```

My gulp css task is:

```
gulp.task('css', function() {
    gulp.src(config.paths.css)
        .pipe(concat('bundle.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.dist + '/css'));
});
```

And my watch task is:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(config.paths.html, ['html']);
    gulp.watch(config.paths.js, ['js', 'lint']);
    gulp.watch(config.paths.css, ['css']);
});
```

The rest works without problems. It is probably something small that I do not see.

EDIT

[image: Structure]

I tried also to change paths to :

```
'./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
'./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css',
'./node_modules/toastr/package/toastr.css',
'./src/css/*.css'
```

And connect task is :

```
gulp.task('connect', function(){
    connect.server({
        root : ['dist'],
        port : config.port,
        base : config.devBaseUrl,
        livereload : true
    })
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any typos in one of those urls or maybe one of the files doesn't exist?

    'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css',
    'node_modules/toastr/package/toastr.css',
    "src/css/main.css"

Comment: and when you say it doesn't work, do you mean, if you save any of those 4 files the watch task doesn't run the css task at all? Have you got any errors in the cli? The obvious difference is that you don't prefix your css files with `./` but other than that I can't see anything wrong with your syntax. Also you mix `'` and `"` but that shouldn't make much difference

Comment: The watch task doesn't work, I think. When I refresh the page then it works. I tried also with ./ in the paths but the same problem. The css task works fine, and I do not get any errors.

Comment: When you refresh the page the gulp watch task is working and when you save css file it doesn't? Are you sure you're not trying to do livereload? If yes (judging by your latest edit), do you have a browser `livereload` extension?

Comment: When I refresh the page then I see the changes that I made in css file. All the rest works perfect, thus livereloading is set to true. I updated my question.

Comment: So just to clarify, when you save a css file, in your CLI, you can see the watch task running css, correct? The only thing that you don't see is in your browser, the css is not updated without manually refreshing the page?

Comment: Try including `watch` task as a dependency for `connect` task...
`gulp.task('connect',['watch'], function(){ .... })`

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27325207/gulp-connect-and-connect-reload

Comment: Nothing helps. I've tried everything, but the problem is till exists. @kaspero Yes, I see watch task running css, but I don't see it in my browser without refreshing.

Comment: So your watch task is fine then, your livereload is not properly configured

Comment: I solved it. I just added `.pipe(connect.reload());`  at the end of css task and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I only changed the css task to :

```
gulp.task('css', function() {
    gulp.src(config.paths.css)
        .pipe(concat('bundle.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.dist + '/css'));
        .pipe(connect.reload());
});
```

And t worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

In your config, change 
"src/css/main.css" to "./src/css/main.css".

Also instead of compiling the following by your way,

```
'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css',
'node_modules/toastr/package/toastr.css',
```

You can just use gulp-useref and do it this way

```
// inside your index.html
<head>
    <!-- build:css css/combined.css -->
    <link href="css/one.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/two.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <!-- endbuild -->
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks. I solved it already. I just added `.pipe(connect.reload());`  at the end of css task and it worked.